# if statement with INSERT as then clause (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am making a conditional insert but i having trouble making one.

the condition is something like this

```
if(select count(*) from employee < 3, insert into employee (name) values ("lisa");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into employee(name)
    select 'lisa'
   where (select count(*) from employee) < 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
SET some_var = (select count(*) from employee);

if(some_var < 3) then
    insert into employee (name) values ("lisa");
end if
```

or like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count into @some_var FROM employee;
if(@some_var < 3) then
    insert into employee (name) values ("lisa");
end if;
```